# Pin Extractor to remove female pins from 0.1" crimp connector housings

Tags: connector, header, wire-terminals

I have a lot of jumper wires with pre-crimped female terminals 0.1" (2.54mm) single-pin housings. I need accurately pull out a wire with precrimped female terminations from crimp connector housing (I need only pre-crimped wire, housing not needed). I used just pliers to crack the housing, but this often breaks the crimp terminals too. I know there is small dedicated "extractor" tool for that, can anyone advice a proper one?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just lift the tab with a pin or tiny flat screwdriver blade.  Just a light touch is needed to release the pin.

Comment: I use X-acto knife for this purpose, although the procedure is unreliable and may lead to a broken latch. Good question.

Comment: @Ale..chenskial. you don't pull the plastic, you push the metal.  Haven't ever broken any

Comment: The pin end of a jumper wire will lift the tab, and is usually at hand.  You may then have to bend it back down again.

Comment: You might try fabing one out of steel shim stock.

Comment: I think the thin exacto knife probably works best. After you do 20 or 30 of them you will become very skilled at it.

Comment: Same here - I have a very thin, like #0, flat blade screwdriver I use, came as part of one of those cheap 6 precision screwdriver sets in a plastic case, probably the only other use it would have is tightening a screw on eye glasses.  Push the pin in completely, lift the plastic a little and hold it while pulling the pin out.  You could google "Dupont pin extractor" or "Dupont square pin extractor" or "0.025" square pin extractor", maybe you can figure out which one is used with 0.025" crimp terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a small flat screwdriver or a knife to lift up the latch (which is on the top side of the housing in your picture) and pull the wire out of the housing while the latch is lifted.

If you don't need to reuse the housing you can simply break or cut the latch off.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-InoAbkNVdQ) showing the process.